# View the stock status for individual product variants in admin panel

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

is it possible to do so that in the admin panel in the product view make it so that the number of available products for each variant is displayed as in the example below?:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQRPG.png)

I have absolutely no idea how to do that. I will be grateful for your help

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't tried anything because I don't know much about it

Comment: To assist you better, it would be beneficial if you could share the code you've tried so far. This will enable us to identify any potential issues or suggest improvements.

Comment: @AdamMak Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Add the code in your active theme functions.php file.
First create new column using the filter `manage_edit-product_columns`

```
     function add_variation_id_stock_column($columns) {
            $new_columns = array();
        
            foreach ($columns as $key => $label) {
                $new_columns[$key] = $label;
    // Here you can set the column to be shown after name column or any other column u want. 
//If you are not sure about the column name using inspector tool of your browser check the column ID.
                if ($key === 'name') { 
                    $new_columns['variation_id_stock'] = 'Variation ID | Stock'; //Name it as you want
                }
            }
        
            return $new_columns;
        }
        
        add_filter('manage_edit-product_columns', 'add_variation_id_stock_column');
```

After that using `manage_product_posts_custom_column` action you can pull the data you want.

```
function variation_id_stock_column_content($column, $post_id) {
    if ($column === 'variation_id_stock') {
        $product = wc_get_product($post_id);
        if ($product->is_type('variable')) {
            $variations = $product->get_children();
            foreach ($variations as $variation_id) {
                $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);
                $stock_quantity = $variation->get_stock_quantity();
                $variation_id = $variation->get_id();
                echo '<p>Variation ID: ' . $variation_id . ' | Stock: ' . $stock_quantity . '</p>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '-'; //Do something else if its not variable product
        }
    }
}

add_action('manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'variation_id_stock_column_content', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code goes in the functions.php of your theme or child theme. Tested and works.
[image]

```
    // Add a custom column to the products admin table
function add_custom_variations_column($columns) {
    $columns['product_variations'] = 'Product Variations';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_product_posts_columns', 'add_custom_variations_column');

// Display variation data in the custom column
function display_custom_variations_column($column, $post_id) {
    if ($column === 'product_variations') {
        $product = wc_get_product($post_id);

        if ($product->is_type('variable')) {
            $variations = $product->get_children();

            if (!empty($variations)) {
                $variation_titles = array();

                foreach ($variations as $variation_id) {
                    $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);
                    $variation_titles[] = $variation->get_title();
                }

                echo implode(', ', $variation_titles);
            } else {
                echo 'No variations';
            }
        } else {
            echo '-';
        }
    }
}
add_action('manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'display_custom_variations_column', 10, 2);

// Make the custom column sortable
function make_variations_column_sortable($columns) {
    $columns['product_variations'] = 'product_variations';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-product_sortable_columns', 'make_variations_column_sortable');
```